# Почему опять не получается htacces

Tags: .htaccess

вот адреса

```
http://film.lc/index.php/multfilm-Angry-Birds-v-kino/
http://film.lc/index.php/serial-Vodolej/
http://film.lc/index.php/film-V-poiske/
```

собственно что нужно

```
http://film.lc/multfilms/multfilm-Angry-Birds-v-kino/
http://film.lc/serials/serial-Vodolej/
http://film.lc/films/film-V-poiske/
```

соответственно. Адресов великое множество
пытаюсь решить так

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST}^/index\.php/([a-z0-1]+)-([a-z0-1\-]+)+
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1s/$1-$2 [L,R=301]
```

но ничего не получается объясните пожалуйста что я делаю не так и как правильно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы убрать index.php из ссылки установите вместо вашего кода - вот такой:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index.php$ / [QSA,R]
```

Далее, для структуры `http://адрес_сайта/категория/название`
нужно выставить в настройках сайта формирование такого типа ссылок.

Comment: а нельзя не просто убрать ссылку ? а добавить перенеся название категории вместо индекса ? При помощи регулярки ?

Comment: можно сделать замену index.php на следующее выражение после / и прибавлять к нему "s", но значит сколько у вас таких категорий - столько и должно быть таких условий. 
P.S. Вы какую-то CMS используете или самописное всё?

Comment: я использую фраимворк yii2

Comment: @Sergalas Тогда я так понимаю вы сами формируете URL, да? Можете показать каким образом вы это делаете?

Comment: вам весь роутер показывать ? вы уверены?

Comment: @Sergalas нет, для создания URL какого вы хотите - нужно перебирать метод createURL(). Можете ознакомиться сами с подробной инструкцией: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/ru/topics.url

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44735/discussion-between-sergalas-and-legionary).